# Unhandled rejection Error: Chrome still being created

Tags: tokbox

When I use `{ insertDefaultUI: false }` to create a video I get an "Unhandled rejection Error: Chrome still being created" when trying to cleanup after I'm done with `session.disconnect()`.

Any ideas...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm on the TokBox dev team.

The error is not something you should be concerned with, it's something internal to the SDK.

The bug is that the error is appearing at all. I have created a bug report and this error should disappear in a future release. Until then you can safely ignore it.

Thanks for the report.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the quick response time.

Comment: This is still not fixed two months later. :/

Comment: It's fixed in the next release, v2.12

Answer (score 0):

```
I'm having the very same problem when trying to unpublish my publisher
Could you guys provide a solution?

Unhandled rejection Error: Chrome still being created
    at Object.chromeMixin.reset (https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.js:41755:16)
    at reset (https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.js:42837:19)
    at Publisher.destroy (https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.js:43211:7)
    at defaultAction (https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.js:43524:20)
    at executeDefaultAction (https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.js:25584:19)
    at Object.api.dispatchEvent (https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.js:25735:7)
    at Publisher.self.dispatchEvent (https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.js:25427:19)
    at Object.streamDestroyed (https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.js:43527:16)
    at Object.unpublishFromSession (https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.js:43507:16)
    at Session.unpublish (https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.js:47031:19)
    at Object.me.stop (https://x/rt.js:498:17)
    at b.$scope.callBreak (https://x/ler.js:16:24)
    at fn (eval at compile (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:239:266), <anonymous>:4:165)
From previous event:
    at createChromeMixin (https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.js:41672:21)
    at new Publisher (https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.js:42826:23)
    at Object.initPublisher (https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.js:44275:21)
    at Object.me.start (https://x/rt.js:457:27)
    at b.$scope.start (https://x/ler.js:6:24)
    at fn (eval at compile (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:239:266), <anonymous>:4:161)
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:284:187)
    at b.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:148:347)
    at b.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:149:52)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:284:239)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:4:8549)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:4:5252)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late, but I'll share my findings. When using a custom UI on your publisher, use the following event:

```
publisher.on('streamDestroyed',function(event){ event.preventDefault();});
```

This disallows opentok calling widget destroying events which causes the exception related to this question, however now I don't know how to stop the stream lol, since if I call event.target.destroy() will generate the same exception, lol ... so I'm trying to figure that out.

Comment: You reply almost a month later and then you point me to something that says:

"not something you should be concerned" (Well yeah I am concerned, it crashes my application)

Plus, guess what? It didn't magically disappear so I just opted in for using your layout ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Hi. I wasn't aware it crashes your app, you didn't mention that. Can you please provide more information? I'd like to know how to reproduce this issue. Also, the fix for this error has not been released yet, it will be fixed in a future version.